# How to assert that a string has a newline character and, if so, remove it

Tags: bash, string

I have a string that is the result of some operation I have no control over. When I print this variable using `echo`, I get:

```
echo $myvar
hello
```

However, when I do

```
if [ $myvar = "hello" ]; then
    echo they are equal
else
    echo they are not equal
fi
```

I always get that they are not equal. I suspect this is because of a `newline` character.

The string also behaves strangely. When I do:

```
newVAR="this is my var twice: "$myvar$myvar
echo $newVAR
```

I get:

```
hellois my var twice: hello
```

How can I check if this is in fact due to a `newline` and, if so, remove it?

Comment: In Bash you can `printf '%q\n' "$string"` to get an escaped version of any string. For example: `printf '%q\n' 'foo\n'` -> `foo\\n`; `printf '%q\n' $'foo\n'` -> `$'foo\n'`

Comment: You're not quoting the expansion of any of your variables.  If they did have any trailing whitespace, you wouldn't see it with `echo $foo`.  Do `echo "$foo"` instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you have an embedded Carriage-Return (CR, `\r`). This causes the terminal text-insertion point to kick back to the start of the line it is printing. That is why you are seeing the 'hello' at the start of the line in you `$newVAR` example - `sed -n l` displays a readable view of unprintable characters (and end of line).

```
var=ab$'\r'c ; echo "$var";  printf %s "$var" | sed -n l
# output:
cb
ab\rc$
```

You can test for it with a simple bash condition check:

```
[[ $var == *$'\r'* ]] && echo yes || echo no
# output:
yes
```

You can combine the test and fix in one step by testing for `\r`(s) and removing them via:

```
fix="${var//$'\r'/}"; echo "$var"; echo "$fix"
# output:
cb
abc
```

The *fix* uses [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). The particular form used above is for replacing substrings based on your proovided pattern: *`${parameter/pattern/string}`* <--
 This replaces only the first found *pattern* with *string* in variable named *parameter. To replace *all* patterns, you just need to change the first `/` to `//`.

Comment: could you explain your last bit of code? the `fix="....` line?

Comment: @farid99: explanation added to answer, Note `fix` can be `var` itself - or often you can just use the parameter expansion as-is without the need to reassign the (possibly) modified value..

Answer (score 6):

You can represent `\r` as `$'\r'` in bash:

```
if [ "$myvar" = "hello"$'\r' ]; then
    echo they are equal
else
    echo they are not equal
fi
```

Or chop the last `\r` in `myvar`:

```
if [ "${myvar%$'\r'*}" = "hello" ]; then
    echo they are equal
else
    echo they are not equal
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Curiously, in many shells `getopts` is a very likely candidate for a job like this. This may seem counterintuitive at first, but if you consider that `getopts`' primary function is to recognize and offer up for interpretation as many specified single character command-line options as might be found in a concatenated series of same, it might begin to make a little more sense.

To demonstrate, from a `bash` shell:

```
x=$(printf '\n\r%010s\t' hello)
OPTIND=1
while  getopts : na "-$x"
do     printf %q\\n "$OPTARG"
done
```

---

```
$'\n'
$'\r'
\
\
\
\
\
h
e
l
l
o
$'\t'
```

In that way it can sometimes be convenient to allow `getopts` to handle the disassembly as a sort of shell auto-pilot for cases like this. When you do so, you can just screen out unwanted bytes w/ a `case` or `[` test `]` and build your string back-up from byte 1:

```
OPTIND=1 y=$(printf \\n\\r) z=
while  getopts : na "-$x"
do     case $OPTARG in ([!$y])
            z=$z$OPTARG
       esac
done
printf %q\\n "$z"
```

---

```
$'     hello\t'
```

Given this simple example case - and given a shell which supports the parameter expansions already elsewhere mentioned - said expansions will probably serve you better here. But I thought `getopts` might be worth a mention as well in case you weren't aware of its capabilities in this respect. Certainly when I learned of it I found many useful applications for it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While Bash and other shell languages are handy, sometimes it's better to use a true scripting language - like Perl. Perl can replace shell scripts that call other languages such as sed and awk as well as UNIX commands quite easily.  I learned this 20+ years ago when writing C-Shell scripts which in turn called sed, awk, and various UNIX commands - before calling FORTRAN code.  In Perl I would do:

```
chomp($myvar);   # removes the newline char

if("$myvar" eq "hello")   # string comparison
  {
  print "they are equal\n";
  }
else
  {
  print "they are not equal\n";
  }
```